# Chat admin different color?

Tags: php, html, session, chat, admin

I have developed a simple chat system. I am trying to make the admin color red to stand out among the chat users. My method takes the session username and if the session username is the admin then it turns *everyone's* text color red. How can I make it so only the admin color is red (everyone else is black)?

Here is my php code:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
    session_start();

    if  (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
        $userId = $_SESSION['id'];
        $username = $_SESSION['username'];
        $userLabel = $_SESSION['nickname'];
    }

    $connect = mysqli_connect("", "", "", "root");
    mysqli_select_db($connect, "webclyde_root");    
    $result1 = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM chat ORDER by id DESC");
    while ($extract = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
        if ($username == "admin") {
            echo "<br><b><font color='#D00003'>" . $extract['name'] . ":</b></font> " . $extract['message'];
        }
        else {
            echo "<br><b><font color='#000000'>" . $extract['name'] . ":</b></font> " . $extract['message'];
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The font tag is not supported in HTML5. Use a CSS style attribute instead, for example:

```
echo "<br><b><p style='color:#D00003'>" . $extract['name'] . ":</b></p>" . $extract['message'];
```

Example for the if / else logic:

```
if($username=="admin"){
    $color = "#D00003";
} else {
    $color = "#000000";
}

echo "<p style='color:".$color."'>". $extract['name'] . "</p>";
```

Or use the statement RamRaider mentioned instead of the if / else statement:

```
$color = $username=='admin' ? 'red' :'black';
```

Also, you are checking if the session $username is 'admin'. I can imagine you want to check if the username from the database is 'admin'. In that case replace $username with $extract['name'] in the if statement.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, I will use this. But this does not provide any solution to my problem.

Comment: You have to write and else statement and change the color to black when the username != admin.

Comment: try some thing like `$colour=$username=='admin' ? 'red' :'black';`

Comment: Using this same exact method (copy and paste) I get the same problem. All of the usernames are now red when logged onto the admin user.

Comment: Perhaps you want to check if ($extract['name'] == 'admin') instead of the session variable $username?

Comment: Got it! totally forgot/didn't realize $username was session variable and did not actually pulling from database.. Thank you everyone so much! Such an awesome community.

Answer (score 1):

replace your while statement with this:

```
while ($extract = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
    if ($username == "admin") {
        $color = '#D00003';
    }
    else {
        $color = '#000000';
    }
    echo "<br><b><font style='color:".$color."'>" . $extract['name'] . ":</b></font> " . $extract['message'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately the same issue. Perhaps this is because $username is a session variable? I am not sure.

Comment: @GavinYouker can you add this above the $connect variable echo $username; just to check what you are getting.